# Correct implementaiton of SSL certificate on apache2 server?

Tags: linux, security, ssl, ssl-certificate, apache2

**Situation:**

I have purchased a multidomain from namecheap/Comodo (it includes 3 domains : the main domain, for example: `maindomain.com` , and two other domains: `sitea.com` and `siteb.com` ).

So far I would like to see if could manage to properly setup the certificate for the main site only at first.

After reading different tutorials online, I believe that the list of files which would possibly need to be edited, in order to successfully using the SSL certificate on the 3 websites, are the following :

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/maindomain.com.conf
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf 
/etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

**List of files for the certificate that were downloaded :**

```
115155984.ca-bundle
115155984.crt
```

*(please note that the file 115155984.ca-bundle does not have any extension to it)*

Right now, it looks like the site `maindomain.com` seem to be pointing to the server ip adress ( 155.133.130.203 ). I'm not sure why. I've posted below the content of the `maindomain.com.conf` file which is in the `sites-available` directory. There are a few points which could possibly alternate the proper implementation of the certificate.

**My questions are the following:**

- 1) i had a ca-bundle file without the crt extension : must I
  mannually add the crt extension ?
- 2) I didnt get any pem file with the files I downloaded : will the
  PEM file be generated at some point ?
- 3) is my /etc/hosts file correct ? I added multiple lines to make
  sure at least one would do the trick. I'm sure it contains a lot of
  unecessary lines. I posted it below.
- 4) my certificate file is not named maindomain.com.crt but has a
  random number instead, does it matter ?
- 5) my key file which was generated earlier in the process, does not
  have the domain extension .com , it is named like so : maindomain.key
  If I remember it was generated at the same time as the csr file
  earlier (did that step sometime ago)

**The /etc/apache2/sites-available/maindomain.com.conf file**

Here is the content of the maindomain.com.conf file inside the sites-available directory:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
            # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
            # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
            # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
            # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
            # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
            # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
            # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
            #ServerName www.example.com

            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html

            # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
            # error, crit, alert, emerg.
            # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
            # modules, e.g.
            #LogLevel info ssl:warn

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
            # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
            # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
            # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
            # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
            #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    </VirtualHost>

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost 155.133.130.203:443>
                ServerAdmin admin@maindomain.com
                ServerName maindomain.com
                ServerAlias www.maindomain.com
                DocumentRoot /var/www/html/maindomain.com/
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                SSLEngine on

                SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/115155984.crt

                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/maindomain.key

                SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/115155984.ca-bundle.crt

                SSLVerifyClient None

                <Directory />
                          Options FollowSymLinks
                          AllowOverride None
                </Directory>
                <Directory /var/www/html/maindomain.com/>
                          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                          AllowOverride All
                          Order allow,deny
                          allow from all
                </Directory>
        </VirtualHost>
    </IfModule>
```

**Unnecessary information inside the /etc/host file**

This is the content of my host file which is in /etc/ . *I had to try a few different things before the PHPMailer could work to send emails from sites*, hence the reason why there's most probably *a lot of unnecessary* lines.

```
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    ::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
    ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
    ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

    155.133.130.203 servername01.maindomain.com
    155.133.130.203 servername01.maindomain.com server01.sitea.com
    127.0.0.1 server01 server01.sitea.com sitea.com
    127.0.0.1 server01 server01.maindomain.com maindomain.com
    155.133.130.203 test.maindomain.com
    155.133.130.203 maindomain.com
    155.133.130.203 sitea.com
```

Comment: `SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/115155984.ca-bundle.crt`  I believe this file doesn't exist.  As you said, it doesn't have the .crt extension.  So don't tell Apache it has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) i had a ca-bundle file without the crt extension : must I mannually add the crt extension ?

File extensions don't matter - unless you're Microsoft. To Apache, a file extension is just part of a longer filename with a dot in it;

> 2) I didnt get any pem file with the files I downloaded : will the PEM file be generated at some point ?

Look at the content of the files you received (with `cat` or `less`) - if they begin with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` (or similar) they are PEM.  If they are binary files, they are not PEM.  You can convert to PEM with `openssl x509 -inform DER -in <file_in_der_format> -out <filename_for_pem_file>`;

> 3) is my /etc/hosts file correct ? I added multiple lines to make sure at least one would do the trick. I'm sure it contains a lot of unecessary lines. I posted it below.

It'll work, although you have duplicated some. Place the IP address once on one line, followed by all the names that should resolve to that IP;

> 4) my certificate file is not named maindomain.com.crt but has a random number instead, does it matter ?

No it doesn't.  You'll need to configure Apache to look for your certificates and private key.  As long as the entries in the conf file matches the filenames and path, it'll work;

> 5) my key file which was generated earlier in the process, does not have the domain extension .com , it is named like so : maindomain.key If I remember it was generated at the same time as the csr file earlier (did that step sometime ago)

See answer to 4) above.

Comment: Gareth, thank you very much for these helpful and straight-to-the-point answers. I finnally managed to get my SSL certificate working on Chrome and some other browsers. For some reasons it gives me an error message on Firefox, but that's another issue. Man, it sure feels great to finally make progress. Thank you again!